# Magisk issue :Device rooted but Magisk not installed

Tags: rooting, troubleshooting, magisk, oneplus-7

Device: OnePlus7, Android 10

**What happened**

- Device was rooted with October security patch updated, custom kernel installed and Magisk Manager hidden (to prevent root detection by an app). All working fine. No problem.
- Updated Magisk Manager to 8.0.3 successfully but it shows Magisk not installed

[image]

- But device is properly rooted and all rooted apps work fine.
- I can see the hidden Magisk Manager in app drawer but tapping it doesn't help. Nothing happens. It tries to open, shows Magisk logo and disappears.
- I can't access the Manager menu to see if I can fix something from there.

**What I tried**

- Flashed Magisk again from laptop. No use.
- Restored stock kernel from backup made by kernel manager app. No use.
- As suggested by [Didgeridoohan's guide](https://www.didgeridoohan.com/magisk/ManagerIssues)  tried these

  - Cleared data of Manager. Uninstalled and installed Magisk Manager. No luck.
  - Uninstalled manager, installed canary manager and set channel to update to canary hoping that may help. Doesn't help.

Device still properly rooted

- Saw this [Github issue](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/issues/2014), Not applicable.

**Things to try**

- Flash Magisk uninstall zip and root again.
- Try manual patching of boot image and flash
- Dirty flash stock ROM - not possible because device is rooted and would result in boot loop.
- **Any other simpler option?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alecxs [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/231189/131553) (thanks) led me to a different and easier solution.

I uninstalled the manager and tapped on the hidden manager and it opened up with the correct status! Ridiculously simple.

[image]

Note to myself :Remember to unhide Magisk Manager before updating next time

Answer (score 3):

- install 3rd party app like Link2SD or DevTools
- get the pkgname for hidden Magisk Manager
- uninstall hidden Magisk Manager from cmd line

  ```
  adb shell cmd package uninstall <pkgname>
  ```
- reinstall Magisk Manager