# "can't login on a rooted device" and banking apps not working on rooted devices with MagiskHide+SafetyNet on

Tags: rooting, lineageos, magisk

- Samsung S9 Plus
- Lineage OS 17.1 with `/data` encrypted
- GApps `pico`
- `Magisk` + `Magisk Manager` + `MagiskHide` with `SafetyNet` on => `basicintegrity=OK` + `ctsProfile=OK` + `evalType=OK` (blueish screen)

Several apps that are (mostly) related to finance (Revolut, XE, etc.) are refusing to start because my device is rooted.

Several forums that I've read through advise to do the above, i.e., `Magisk` + `SafetyNet`, which I have done. However, nothing of that works. I've even tried to "hide" `/sbin/su` by renaming it for a moment, but that didn't do the trick either.

I read something about GApps `pico/picoG` being the culprit, saying that `micro/microG` should be the bare minimum to effectively "hide" the "rooted" status, but I'm not sure about that, and reinstalling everything isn't something that I am particularly looking forward to, unless there is no other way.

I know that this is a cat-and-mouse game, but any other suggestions I should try?

Comment: first, hiding su is not necessary. instead, hide magisk manager itself. second, note on recent android safetynet is bonded to bootloader lock state, no workaround (so far)

Comment: @alecxs But if the bootloader state would be the problem than shouldn't the SafetyNet tests fail? But according to OP both tests were successful. Therefore I would assume that the apps check the OS and identify LineageOS (which does not hide itself).

Comment: @alecxs and @Robert, based on your comments, how to hide Magisk Manager (delete the app?) as well as the LineageOS identification string (if there's such a thing, i.e., `uname` of some sort)? Is this achievable?

Comment: Robert is right, didn't notice safetynet passed. i don't use magisk so can't tell you, but i know it is possible to [hide magisk manager](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/231184) even from itself. according to xda, magisk *could* manipulate SafetyNet but is no longer able to hide bootloader state? https://www.xda-developers.com/safetynet-hardware-attestation-hide-root-magisk

Comment: @alecxs, those are interesting links, thanks. I've installed & run `SafetyTest Helper Sample` as advised on XDA => all green. I've also extracted the `SafetyNetResponse` string through logcat => `evaluationType:BASIC`, which isn't as alarming as if it were `HARDWARE_BACKED`. So perhaps the app does identify LineageOS...

Comment: Could it be that the apps are checking the props `ro.build.host`, `ro.build.flavor`, or `ro.build.display.id`, which all contain `lineage`?

Comment: every app is different, but i don't believe banking apps can be cheated that easy. i recommend to install on other device with stock android first, to figure out if unlocked bootloader is showstopper already

Comment: The worry now is: how long until all apps use this detection method (Displax reported in the post you sent above that McDonald's already implemented it).

Comment: installed Revolut on my vanilla android 7.0 rooted with SuperSU. Couldn't test payment as i don't have account but the app did not complain any issue with unlocked bootloader or rooting

Comment: With an older version of Revolut (<7.30.3), it works fine as decribed [https://community.revolut.com/t/revolut-will-start-blocking-jalbroken-rooted-devices/183928](here), but with a later version and other banking apps, it breaks. I've been looking into Chainfire's `hidesu` package, but I'm not sure if it'll work with Android 10 (as devel seems to have stopped in 2017, and since `/data` can't be decrypted with TWRP, I don't know how to install that package, but I will try it.