# Magisk manager not detecting magisk installation

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, magisk, systemless-root

Device: itel A11, Android 6

Before the installation of  magisk v22, my magisk installation was working fine, so I updated the magisk through direct installation and rebooted my phone but magisk manager wasn't detecting magisk.
I tried flashing magisk on my boot image and flashed the patched image with fastboot and spd flash tool but magisk manager  wasn't still detecting magisk.
I updated to the latest canary version and tried the same thing but to no avail, so I tried flashing my stock ROM but replaced my boot image with the patched boot image still nothing.
Today I came across this thread [Magisk issue :Device rooted but Magisk not installed](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231184/magisk-issue-device-rooted-but-magisk-not-installed?newreg=60441132722b41c0ae20cf4474d5477c) that shows exactly the problem I have and he solved the problem by uninstalling the repackaged magisk manager, but now my problem is I flashed my phone and I doubt if the repackaged magisk manager will still be in the phone but why is magisk manager not still detecting magisk [image: magisk app screenshot]

Comment: This happened to me. Here is what I did. I uninstalled Magisk Manager app. Downloaded latest Magisk apk from GitHub. Renamed its extension to ZIP. Went into recovery and flashed that zip. Rebooted and Magisk Manager was installed and was working fine.

Comment: @Firelord signature verification failed and I can't use custom recovery because they don't support my device

Comment: Unhiding of Magisk manager is essential. Please do post your fix afterwards- for now , I am deleting my answer(not relevant)

Comment: @beeshyams, I can't un-hide magisk manager since I flashed my device with my stock ROM, except the app remains even after the phone being flashed

Comment: Very unusual. I would suggest make a backup of data, wipe data, flash stock ROM and patch boot image for root